# Codingbat.com endX not resolving "other tests"

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on a recursion problem from codingbat.com which states

```
Given a string, compute recursively a new string where all the lowercase 'x' chars have been moved to the end of the string.
```

It passes all of the examples except for the example that says "other tests."  Since i can't see what "other tests" are referring to, I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's my code

```
public String endX(String str) {
  return endX2(str, 0, str.length());
}

public String endX2(String str, int n, int len){
  if(len == 0) return str;
  if(n == len-1) return str;
  if(str.substring(n,n+1).equals("x")){
    return str.substring(0,n) + (endX2(str.substring(n+1) + "x", n, len-1));
  }
  else return endX2(str, n+1, len);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have an additional method as it's unnecessary. You also have an additional check - `if(n == len-1) return str;` - that isn't needed.

The problem you're facing is the fact you're using unchecked indices and are getting lucky when the strings used do not end with an 'x' or a number of 'x's. If I use your code against `String xs = "xfooxbarxx";` gets me a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I haven't debugged the code extensively, but that should bring some understanding to the reason why it fails on the "other" tests. Take a look at my version and investigate for yourself where the issue may lie and how to perhaps make your code a bit more concise.

```
public String endX(String str) {
  if(str.length() == 0)
    return "";
  return str.startsWith("x") ? 
    endX(str.substring(1)) + "x" :
    String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)) + endX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PS: This is WAY WAY longer than it needs to be.

```
/*
Alright here is what we need to do...
Step 1: Get all the 'x' chars into a String.
Step 2: Get all NON 'x' chars into a String.
Step 3 (goal): Concencate (combine) the NON 'x' String first then the 'x' String in that order.
Solution Notes: Instead of using an index variable to go through a String, we could 'substring' off the first char in the String each time, cutting until we are down to the base case, for the sake of showing recursive logic I used an index varible. However on Arrays or any other collection, you need an index varible to access that element ant that spot or (index).
*/
public String endX(String str) {
  //Ternary operator used here...could be written as a full if then else statement.
  //Ternary operator logic: if the length is 0 return "", else return getNonX(str, "", 0) + getX(str, "", 0);
  return (str.length() == 0) ? "" : getNonX(str, "", 0) + getX(str, "", 0);

  //NOTICE in the parts [getNonX(str, "", 0)] and [getX(str, "", 0)] 
  //there is an empty String in the middle, that is there to hold or gather the
  //chars, 'x' or not. We fill those empty Strings up in each recursive helper
}
public String getX(String str, String x, int index) {
  //We are at the end, and if the last char IS an 'x'...

  if(index == str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(index) == 'x'){
  return x + 'x'; //...put that last 'x' on the 'x' String.
  }

  //We are at the end and if the last char IS NOT an 'x'...

  else if(index == str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(index) != 'x'){
  return x; //...just return what we got.
  }    
  //When we see an 'x' but we aren't at the end...

  if(index < str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(index) == 'x'){
  x += 'x'; //...append 'x' to the 'x' String.
  }

  return getX(str, x, index + 1); //recur, moving the index up
}
public String getNonX(String str, String nonX, int index) {
  //We are at the end, and if the last char IS NOT an 'x'...

  if(index == str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(index) != 'x'){
  return (nonX + str.charAt(index)); //...append that char to the 'nonX' String
  }

  //We are at the end and if the last char IS an 'x'...

  else if(index == str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(index) == 'x'){
  return nonX; //...just return what we got.
  }

  //When we see a non 'x' char and we aren't at the end...

  if(index < str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(index) != 'x'){
  nonX += str.charAt(index); //...append that char to the 'nonX' String
  }

  return getNonX(str, nonX, index + 1); //recur, move the index up
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code...

```
public String endX(String str) {
  if(str.length() <=1) return str;
  if(str.charAt(0) == 'x') return endX(str.substring(1)) + 'x';
  return str.charAt(0) + endX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for the green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. As such the already [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24129419/5698098) from ChiefTwoPencils is basically the same code solution as yours. Only posting code as an answer may be OK sometimes, however in general it's much better to explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the other answers.

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).